# Want to Re-render an other component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Actually I want another component to Re-render if some changes are made in some other component, parent of both component contain some other component that I don't want them to Re-render. just want when the function is executed it went back to parent and only Re-render the specific component. can't use Window.location.reload because it refresh all the items anything that can rerender only the triggered component. following code is just meant for the idea. as changes are done in First it must be reflected in the other component

`

```
{/* Parent Component*/}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <SecondComponent />
                
                <firstComponent />
                <anotherComponent />
                <anotherComponent />
                <anotherComponent />
                
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;

{/* 1 child component */}

import { React } from "react";
const FirstComponent = () => {

    const handleChange=(event) =>{
        const {name, value}=event.target
        localStorage.setItem(name, value)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-11 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                        <h1>All Searches</h1>
                    <input type='text' name='tab1' onChange={handleChange} />
                    <input type='text' name='tab2' onChange={handleChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default FirstComponent;

{/* 2nd Child Component */}

import React from 'react';

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

class SecondComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(){

        super();

        this.state={

            tab1:localStorage.getItem("tab1"),
            tab2:localStorage.getItem("tab2"),
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="d-inline-flex" style={{ background: "#242F84", width: "100%" }}>
                    <NavLink to="/" className="Home">
                        <p className="mb-0 FS_28 px-2 White" >Home</p>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/AllSearches">
                        <p className="mb-0 White">All Searches</p>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/AllSearches">
                        <p className="mb-0 White">{this.state.tab1}</p>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/AllSearches">
                        <p className="mb-0 White">{this.state.tab2}</p>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            </>
        );

    }
}

export default SecondComponent;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To re-render a component the standard way is to change its state. The question is - If a component's state is not changed, why would you want to re-render it?

I see you are using local storage - I suggest you use local state as much as you can in stead of local storage to manage this type of information.

Comment: i have used your suggestion and created and array component and imported it in my parent component and rendering it then in one child component.
i want to add and subtract the objects from other component into that array component, like i want that on click handleClick work and it deletes the object in array containing the specified id in the array of that component and if their is form and submit it creates object in that array component
` {*DataComponent*} 
const Data=[
 {
 _id:1,
title:'aba'
}
]
{*first Component*}
<p>use data here from that data component</p>

{*Add from 2*}
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472416/add-and-subtract-object-into-array-present-another-component-in-react